# Why would a question with a valid re-title, be reverted to a non-question title?

Tags: discussion

[How do I make a machine "blank screen" for a period of time (as a penalty) if certain noise levels are reached?](https://superuser.com/questions/545329/blank-screen-if-kids-yell-too-much)

I spent a few minutes getting familiar with what was in the body and comments/answers to the question so I could rephrase the title cleanly into a question.  And then (by the author, I guess) the title was reverted to the original non-question title.

So, why would the validly retitled question have the title reverted on it?
Does this count as a bug?

I'm half temped to apply the same retitle I submitted before, but I wanted to ask before doing that.  The current (and original) title is crap, and not a question.  I'm befuddled as to why it would have been reverted.

Comment: it's not a bug, post owners have the ability to revert edits, much like how folks with 3k+ rep

Comment: @Sathya, OK.  Good to know it wasn't a bug.  In the future when this happens again (which looks to be a very infrequent thing, since most OPs appear to appreciate my paraphrases) is asking like this the right way to approach it?

Comment: absolutely, yes - meta is the preferred way to discuss such matters :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rolled back to your edit. I really don't understand why the OP felt the need to revert your change.

Comment: That makes two of us.

Answer (score 1):

Typically questions should be phrased as a question with the who, what, where, when, why, and how.  However this isn't your typical question as it garnered a high amount of traffic, and votes.  Also, and more importantly, the title did state the original intent of the OP.  IMO, as long as the title gives a semblance of the problem at hand it's ok.  For example take a look at this title:

> [Transatlantic ping faster than sending a pixel to the screen?](https://superuser.com/questions/419070/transatlantic-ping-faster-than-sending-a-pixel-to-the-screen)

Yes it does have a question mark, but in reality it's not a question.  Where's the who, what, where, when, why and how of this question?  If we were to hold the same standards here, the question should be rephrased as:

> Why is a transatlantic ping faster than sending a pixel to a screen?

Taking on a question mark doesn't make the post an actual question.  We could do the same for this post:

> Blank Screen If Kids Yell Too Much?

But it's still not a question per se.  However, from both titles you can get the basic idea of what the OP is having a problem with, or the end goal they are seeking.

I'm not saying that your edit was wrong, nor was @Oliver's actions, I'm just trying to present a case where the OP may have felt that it was ok.

Comment: I guess that is part of my point.  A statement, or a statement that ends in a question is less likely to engage the thought process of people looking through the questions.